# why is deleting a db-directory located in var/lib/mysql has no effect to my website?

Tags: mysql, server

I don´t get it. Everytime when i´ve deleted all the content of a mysql-directory in var/lib/mysql/mywebsite, my website still runs on any device or browser without any negative effect. If i look in phpMyAdmin, the database is completely empty! If i delete the whole directory (with directory itself), it has an effect (site is gone), but after restoring this directory with an different database, the old version appears on the website again instead of the new restored database!

BUT if i clear my database tables of that same database in phpMyAdmin, it affects my site immediately... why is that, could it be, that there is any kind of DB-caching on my Vserver?

After:

```
service mysqld restart
```

everything is normal, means: right content / right database.

Would be nice if somebody could help me with this.

CentOS 6.9 (Final)‬
Plesk Onyx 17.5.3 Update Nr. 4
Wordpress 4.7.4 (without caching enabled / caching plugins)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Unix, if a process has a file open while another process deletes it, the process can still access the file -- it doesn't really go away until all processes close it. The `mysqld` process already has the database files open. So deleting the directory doesn't affect the contents of the database until you restart it, which forces it to reopen all the files.

Also, `mysqld` loads indexes into memory when possible, and doesn't reread them from the file if it doesn't need to.

In general, you should avoid manipulating the files used by a database directly while the daemon is running, the results can be very unpredictable. You should preferably use commands in the database client to manage the database contents, but if you need to restore it from a file-level backup, you should shut down the daemon first.

Comment: ok great, i understand. Thanks a lot. The reason why i tried this way is, that i have problems setting up a cron for mysqldump or plesk db! Problems with rights and error codes regarding the dump file. :/

Answer (score 0):

Try drop database in PhpMyAdmin, Or execute in your console.

```
DROP DATABASE database_name;
```

Comment: If i drop the databases in PhpMyAdmin and restore it afterwards with a different database the old one appears! It´s very weird!

Comment: Maybe the one you database you restored is also the same database as old :D

Comment: Forgotten to say, that i restore by copying the directory with: rsync -avh

Comment: This seems to be an answer for a completely different question. He's not asking how to empty his database, but why deleting the directory doesn't do it.

Comment: No it has something to do with just copying the directory in var/lib/mysql

Comment: Dont copy. instead. try importing it using phpmyadmin. Try this. create a different database name. import the database file you want to restore and edit the configuration of your system on that database name. then check if the old database still appears.

Comment: The normal way works, of course... I´ve tried an easy way to restore a database with another with just copying the folder. Thats why i was wondering! It seems that linux or plesk needs a trigger (like actions in phpMyAdmin) for these folders to work ?!